# Turn zeroes in a string to spaces

Tags: java, string

Suppose I have a string:

```
String s = "34205478200044520042";
```

I want to change this string so that a 0 becomes a space, but consecutive 0s are treated as only 1 space still.

Meaning the new string would look like "342 54782 4452 42"
How do you treat any number of 0s to equal one space?

Comment: Please show an attempt with your question.

Comment: Have a look at regular expressions

Answer (score 3):

The regular expression `0+` matches any number of zeroes, because `+` in a regular expression means "one or more of the preceding subexpression".  So you can write

```
String newString = myString.replaceAll("0+", " ");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) method to replace a regular expression of a sequence of `0` characters with a space:

```
String result = s.replaceAll("0+", " ");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions to achieve this:

```
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("[0]+", " "));
// + indicates that the character set (in this case "0") must match at least once.
// Displays 342 54782 4452 42
```